# mysql get row number from table where a column value is equal to a specific value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where results of modeltest are given in a column in descending order. Now I want to get the row number of a specific row. Here is the example table:

[image]

So when i will search a with userid=44, it should return 3. Again when i will search with userid=11, it should return 4. How can I do this ? If anyone could kindly help me out.

Comment: how are you searching? show your code.

Comment: use where  and select

Comment: At the time of search set the count which start with 1 when the user id will be match the return that count

Comment: Hey there. Please read the following and amend the question with verifiable code:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
$stmt = PDO::prepare('SELECT id FROM table WHERE userid = ?');
$userId = 44;

$stmt->execute([$userId]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo $result->id;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

A simple where clause will achieve this.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE userid = 44
```

Swap table and userid value to whatever is needed.

Hope this helps